# Having a OpenStreetMap on DKAN

Tags: openstreetmap, dkan

I am trying to have a map shown on the front page of DKAN, but my research has not given me a clear answer if that is even possible. I find DKAN quite not flexible when it comes to these things, but it may be the lack of experience I have.

I saw that [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/) has some interesting projects like the [OSRM](http://project-osrm.org/) and [Nominatim](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/search.html). And I would like to use them on my [dkan](https://getdkan.org/)-website. But I can't figure out how to put a map on the website? Does someone have experience with it? Is it even possible? The idea of course is to be able to use it more interactively and not just having a link to OSM.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenStreetMap, OSRM and Nominatim website use the javascript leaflet library to display the interactive map https://leafletjs.com/

In the first tutorial https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/ you will see that you can select a tile (map images) provider URL, there's many providers available and all have free pricing tiers https://switch2osm.org/providers/

Next you'll see a 'plugins' page on the leafletjs website. For a search box look at geocoding, for OSRM look at routing. Again for each there are multiple available plugins and multiple available providers of data.

Depending on the website framework or programming language you use you might be able to find tutorial specific to that + leafletjs. I've built several websites with leaflet in the past.